# manage project on github

Tags: git, github

I want to put my project to the github, but I always failed.
I use following steps to do it:

1. create a new repository on github,
2. In my disk, I create a folder LocalGit and initial it. Then I use 
   `git pull git@github.com:myAccount/myProject.git`
3. I add the project directory TestPro to the LocalGit, and then using:
   `git add .`
   `git commit -m "inital"`
4. Finally, I try to push it to the github, using :
   `git push -u origin master`

After that, I open the github in safari, and my project exists. 
But the problem is the folder TestPro can't be open, and there is nothing under it.

Could anyone tell me how to add existing project to the github?
I have read the instructions on github, but I still can't find the solution and where am I wrong.

The local project I refer is a local git repository. Does it matter? should I checkout it first?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the remote?  Sounds like you skipped a step.

Comment: GitHub has a very good help page at [Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line](http://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line). I am git-challenged, and the instructions have always worked well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After created you project on github, you have :

1. To clone you project in local, used `git clone git@github.com:myAccoun/myProject.git`
2. touch test;git add test;git commit -a -m "first commit"
3. after you right : git push origin master

git pull is git fetch and git merge. Used it after to refresh your repository.
.git is automatically manage by git, so it's no necessary to add to track.

Comment: I follow your step, and Only replace step2 by: copying my project folder to the reposority and using add and commit. However, the the folder can be seen in the github but it can't be open and the icon of it is green.

Comment: I found the problem: the local project I copyed having git versions.

Answer (score 1):

After creating repo on github

1) configure ssh-keys, then set your git.username and git.email

2) Clone repo using git clone

```
git clone git@github.com:username/somerepo.git
```

3) Make changes, commit it to local repo and push to remote by git push

5)????

6) Proffit

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a new repo on GitHub, the simplest way to use it is:

- to clone it locally (which defines a remote 'origin' in that local repo)
- copy your project in that local cloned repo
- push

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the remote location before pushing it. 
    git remote add origin git@github.com:myAccount/myProject.git
http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/ Go to the "more about remotes"

Answer (score 0):

The steps are :

```
1. cd "/path/to/project_folder"
2. git init
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "Your Message"
5. git remote add github https://github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo_name]
6. git push origin master
```

or, if you want to clone first. Then,

```
1. git clone git@github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo_name]
```

Then, you can make changes to the files that you cloned.

Next, use the following commands :

```
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "Your Message"
4. git remote add github https://github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo_name]
4. git push origin master
```